# Azure pipeline container pytest

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

I have this Azure DevOps Pipeline

```
stages:
- stage: unit_tests
  displayName: Run Tests
  jobs:
  - job: create_image
    displayName: Create image
    pool:
      name: SomePool
    steps:
    - script: |
        docker build -t someImage:latest -f Dockerfile .
        docker push repo/someImage:latest
      displayName: Create Base Image
        - job:
    displayName: Unit tests
    dependsOn: create_image
    pool: 
      name: SomePool
    container:
      image: someImage:latest
      endpoint: someServiceConnection
    steps:
        - script: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            python -m pip install --user pytest pytest-cov
            <some other commands>
          displayName: Install Dependencies
        - script: |
            python -m pytest -c pytest.ini tests/
          displayName: Run pytest
```

With this setup we suddenly encounter this issue being unable to install pip/pytest

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7eb95ff2b0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f34a25d4670>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytest/
```

I tried moving the `python -m pip install*` to our DockerFile instead to remove timeout issue on run time. Also tried adding pytest to our requirements.txt but got the same results.

```
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
 RUN python -m pip install --user pytest
```

However, running the pipeline now pytest is not found. Also added `pip list` in the script section of my pipeline and pytest does not show up or installed.

```
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pytest
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

We also tried doing the task manually in the same pool machine and got positive results.

Any ideas on either (1) installing pytest using pip on run time or (2) pytest not showing up on run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the privilege option in the container definition

```
container:
  image: someImage:latest
  endpoint: someServiceConnection
  options: --privileged=true
```